# I want to find the Covariance between 1 column with all the other columns in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, covariance

I am trying to analyse the National Stock Exchange Data. I want to calculate the covariance of each stock wrt the index (nifty), using pandas, and there after calculate the beta of each stock. How shall I go about it?

I found the method to calculate the covariance of 1 column with another, but my dataframe has about 36 stock closing price columns, and 1 index closing column. How can i calculate the covariance of all columns wrt the index column with a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to calculate returns of the prices (you are using adjusted closing prices, right?).

```
returns = df.pct_change()
```

Next, you calculate the covariance as a series (I'm using a dictionary comprehension to create the series):

```
index = 'SPY'  # Change to your ticker for the index.
s = pd.Series({symbol: returns[index].cov(returns[symbol]) 
               for symbol in df 
               if symbol != index})
```

This will give you the covariance of each stock with the index.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate betas using `beta = cov(ri,rm)/var(rm)` you can use `DataFrame.cov` from [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) for the numerator.

The example below assumes the index of the DataFrame contains the dates, generated by `to_datetime()`. The market index is CRSP's `vwret`, but any other market index will work as well.

```
get_year = lambda x: x.year
by_year = returns.groupby(get_year) # for yearly betas

def betas(returns, market):
    b=returns.cov()/returns[market].var() # generates cov matrix
    return(pd.Series(b[market], index=list(returns))) # index includes the stock names

beta=betas(returns, 'vwretd')
```

The last line of the function selects only the 'market' column of the covariance matrix. This column contains the betas.

The line below generates betas by year, but I am aware that one generally needs 60-month windows.

```
by_year.apply(betas, 'vwretd')
```

Comment: This will compute the covariance of each stock with every other stock, which can get intractable really quickly. It would be better to avoid this unnecessary computation.